# EXTJS date calculation

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have "startdate" field, that I'm getting its value. Plus I have three other fields: day,month,year. Which I'm also getting its values. Now I have to add day and month and year to startdate to get my new date. Can anybody help me with this, in order to maintain date conditions? e.g: so i don't add 12 days to 25 and get 37.

```
function calDate(){
    var startDate;
    var trs_jour = Ext.getCmp('JOUR').getValue();
    var trs_mois = Ext.getCmp('MOIS').getValue();
    var trs_annee = Ext.getCmp('ANNEE').getValue();

    if(trs_jour!='' || trs_mois!='' || trs_annee!=''){
        var d = new Date(Ext.getCmp('STARTDATE').getValue());
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        var month = d.getMonth()+1;
        var day = d.getDate();
}
```

Comment: Look at the `Ext.Date` class.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Date class defines some basic methods for handling dates.

Provides a convenient method for performing basic date arithmetic. This method does not modify the Date instance being called - it creates and returns a new Date instance containing the resulting date value.

`Ext.Date.add ( date , interval , value )`

PARAMETERS

```
date :  Date
```

The date to modify

```
interval :  String
```

A valid date interval enum value.

```
value :  Number
```

The amount to add to the current date.

```
RETURNS : Date
```

The new Date instance.

Examples :

`// Basic usage: 
var dt = Ext.Date.add(new Date('10/29/2006'), Ext.Date.DAY, 5);
console.log(dt); // returns 'Fri Nov 03 2006 00:00:00'`

`// Negative values will be subtracted:
var dt2 = Ext.Date.add(new Date('10/1/2006'), Ext.Date.DAY, -5);
console.log(dt2); // returns 'Tue Sep 26 2006 00:00:00'`